# In expo-av Video, onPlaybackStatusUpdate is not getting called while video is playing

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-video, expo-av

I'm using **Expo SDK 49** and **expo-av 13.4.1**. I'm using "Video" from "expo-av". Here sometimes callback for onPlaybackStatusUpdate is getting called while video is playing and sometimes it is not getting called. It works on some androids and on some it doesn't and since it is not getting called my states are not updating to show video's current timestamps.

```
updatePlaybackCallback(status) {
        console.log("time", status.positionMillis , status.durationMillis)
        const durationSeconds = (status.positionMillis || status.durationMillis) / 1000;
       /*.... other code for timestamps */
}
```

```
<Video
      ref={this.videoRef}
      source={{
          uri: this.state.videoURL,
      }}
      rate={1.0}
      volume={this.state.playbackInstanceInfo.volume}
      isMuted={false}
      // resizeMode="cover"
      resizeMode="contain"
      shouldPlay={
          this.state.playbackInstanceInfo.state !== "Buffering"
      }
      // useNativeControls

      isLooping={false}
      style={
          this.state.playbackInstanceInfo.fullScreen
              ? {
                  ...styles.fullVideo,
                  width: this.state.width,
                  height: this.state.height,
              }
              : styles.video
      }
      onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(status) =>
          this.updatePlaybackCallback(status)
      }
 />
```

I tried callback with and without 'async', but no success.